# Strange connections on netstat

Tags: http, netstat, trojan

While setting up a new http-server, i found some strange connections showing up in netstat:

[image: netstat]

There is nearly nothing running on this computer - these high ports seems to be for a trojan.

Can anyone help me with informations?

Answer (score 3):

Try `netstat -b`, it prints the executables too which could help identify the cause.